# Is it possible to use meek bridges in orbot?

Tags: bridge, orbot, censorship

I decide to try orbot in a heavily censored environment and can't get it to work. ppl suggests try to put a few bridges in the setting menu. I tried a few obfs3 and obfs4 bridges, and it doesn't help, either.

I heard meek seems to work when other bridges fail, but orbot seems to be different from conventional TBB on a desktop computer, I can't find any options that mention meek bridge in my orbot setting, and bridges.torproject.org doesn't seem to offer any meek bridges.

So my question is, does orbot support meek based connecion yet?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Orbot supports meek, specifically `meek-lite` provided by the `obfs4proxy` binary that's shipped with Orbot.

When you enable bridges (swipe in left, and toggle the 'Bridges' slider to on) it will give you the option to *'Tunnel through Azure'* or *'Tunnel through Amazon'*. Choosing one of these options configures it to use the Amazon or Azure meek bridge.

Comment: Ok. I tried both, they will connect sometimes, but the speed varies quite wildly, and during specific times, doesn't seems to be able to work. Guess I'll have to make do will until I found a better solution.

Comment: Meek bridges are quite slow (and probably overloaded), if obfs4 or other options are available you should probably prefer them.